# Is Identifier in the JLS's production for TypeParameter actually TypeVariable?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, jls, type-variables

I'm reading the JLS, Java SE 8 Edition and I'm stuck at the section about type variables.

[It reads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

> A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class,
> interface, method, and constructor bodies.
>
> A type variable is introduced by the declaration of a type parameter
> of a generic class, interface, method, or constructor (§8.1.2, §9.1.2,
> §8.4.4, §8.8.4).
>
> ```
> TypeParameter: 
>   {TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound] 
>
> TypeParameterModifier: 
>   Annotation 
>
> TypeBound: 
>   extends TypeVariable 
>   extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}
>
> AdditionalBound: 
>   & InterfaceType
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no
> bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed. If a bound
> is declared, it consists of either:
>
> - single type variable T, or
> - a class or interface type T possibly followed by interface types I_1 & ... & I_n.

Regrading the quotes

- *A type variable is an unqualified identifier* (from above)
- *Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound.* (from above)
- *In a class's type parameter section, a type variable T directly depends on a type variable S if S is the bound of T* (from section [8.1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1))

to me -- if my understanding is correct -- it would make sense (more precise, less confusing) to have the `TypeParameter` production as follows:

> ```
> TypeParameter: 
>   {TypeParameterModifier} TypeVariable [TypeBound]
> ```

After all, `TypeVariable` is already defined as

> ```
> TypeVariable:
>   {Annotation} Identifier
> ```

Is my understanding -- the `Identifier` in the JLS's production for `TypeParameter` is actually `TypeVariable` -- correct or am I missing something here?

It confuses me that this section is about type variables, the explanatory text also mentions type variables, but when I try to make the connection to the productions to me it seems that the text is talking about the `Identifier` (hence my question).

The way it is now, reading `Identifier` in this production, suggests to me that this is an identifier for `TypeParameter` and not for `TypeVariable`, which to me indicates that these should be two different things. What is it?

Comment: The purpose of the grammar is to tell you which token sequences are correct. The specified production serves this purpose. Inserting `TypeVariable` instead of `Identifier` would not improve it.

Comment: My question is regarding terminology. Reading the quotes it seems to me that e.g. in `public class Foo<T extends Integer> { ... }` the correct term for `T` is *type variable*. However, when I look at the grammar `TypeVariable` only occurs in `TypeBound: extends TypeVariable`. `TypeVariable` does not appear at the position which matches `T` - `Identifier` does. That makes me wonder if it's correct to refer to `T` as a *type variable* here. Is it? If yes - why not have `TypeVariable` there instead of `Identifier`? At least for me that would have avoided described confusion.

Comment: Doesn't the purpose of the grammar also comprise telling us how to name / refer to the individual syntactical components of a program?

Comment: No, that’s not the purpose of the grammar. The terminology is given in the text, as far as it matters. The main purpose of the specification is to define the *behavior* of a program, but, of course, it wouldn’t work without well defined terms. But the grammar is just given to define the syntax. It seems that historically, at least one author tried to use the grammar for defining semantic constructs, but other authors did not follow, so trying to match the grammar with terms will end up in an inconsistent mess. I wouldn’t even use it to feed a parser but rather create my own, compatible grammar

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you are expecting to this question - the part of the JLS you quoted directly shows that `Identifier` is in this part of the grammar, not `TypeVariable`, but I'm assuming there is no use in telling you what you already know.